# Ionic 3: Could not find support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-build

After adding Android platform (`ionic cordova platform add android`) I've built my Ionic project (`ionic cordova build android`) and I've got a error "Could not find support-compat.aar"

`A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
Could not find support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-compat/26.1.0/support-compat-26.1.0.aar`

`"cordova-android": "6.3.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.12.0"`

Answer (score 3):

Before adding platform and build I've removed all ~/.gradle/ caches files and issue has been solved